# Post a list of lists using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to know how I make a post using Retrofit for send a server to which the result is something like this:

```
 {
  "facebookProfile":{
  "name":"String",
  "education_history":"String",
  "birthday":"String",
  "hometown":"String",
  "email":"String",
  "location":"String"
 },
  "picture":{
  "selfieURL":"String",
  "documentIDs":{
      "frontURL":"String",
      "backURL":"String"
      }
 }
}
```

IDVerification -

```
public class IDVerification {

    private FacebookProfile facebookProfile;

    private Customer customer;

    private Location location;

    private Picture picture;

    private Audio audio;
}
```

FacebookProfile - (have gatter and setter)

```
public class FacebookProfile implements Serializable{

    private String name;

    private String education_history;

    private String birthday;

    private String hometown;

    private String email;

    private String location;
}
```

Picture - (have getter and setter)

```
public class Picture implements Serializable{

    private String selfieURL;

    private DocumentIDs documentIDs;
}
```

Comment: What wxactly did you try? It's pretty straight forward - define a class that represents the response object, it will be parsed from the `json` with your converter (ie. `Gson`)

Comment: I need to create a post to send a set of information so that for the server resembles something above

Answer (score 0):

Define the following Classes:
`FacebookProfile`, `Customer`, `Location`, `DocumentIDs`, `Picture`, `Audio`
and define their properties, getters and setters. `Picture` will look as following:

```
public class Picture {

    private String selfieURL;
    private DocumentIDs documentIDs;


    public String getSelfieURL() {
        return selfieURL;
    }


    public void setSelfieURL(String selfieURL) {
        this.selfieURL = selfieURL;
    }


    public DocumentIDs getDocumentIDs() {
        return documentIDs;
    }


    public void setDocumentIDs(DocumentIDs documentIDs) {
        this.documentIDs = documentIDs;
    }

}
```